# jq add element to each object inside array of objects

Tags: json, jq

If I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "remote" : [
            {
                "id" : 1
            },
            {
                "id" : 2
            },
            {
            "   id" : 3
            }
        ],
        "text_id" : 1
        },
    {
        "remote" : [
            {
                "id" : 4
            },
            {
                "id" : 5
            },
            {
                "id" : 6
            }
        ],
        "text_id" : 2
    }
]
```

How would you add "text_id" field to every object inside .[].remote[] array so it would become

```
[
    {
        "remote" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "text_id" : 1
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "text_id" : 1
            },
            {
            "   id" : 3,
                "text_id" : 1
            }
        ]
        },
    {
        "remote" : [
            {
                "id" : 4,
                "text_id" : 2
            },
            {
                "id" : 5,
                "text_id" : 2
            },
            {
                "id" : 6,
                "text_id" : 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have already spent several hours trying to figure this out. It looks like there has to be a way to do this using foreach directive, but after I checked the manual for it, it seemed to me pretty obscure so I though maybe someone could give an example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq 'map( .text_id as $t
         | .remote |= map( . + {text_id : $t} )
         | del(.text_id)
    )'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `map` for that.

```
.[] |= (.remote[] += {text_id} | del(.text_id))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B6CHO-5TnP)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, your answer looks shorter, although I used jq '.[] | {remote, text_id} | .remote[] + {text_id}' json.log in the end, but it was inspired by your version=) It seems I had those freaking dots messed up when composing objects, because I was trying to do that and only got  jq's error messages, which were not helpful at all.

Comment: @krop Good. `.[] | .remote[] + {text_id}` would do the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use array.map()
You have two levels of array so it should look like this :

```js
const fatArray = [
    {
        remote : [
            {
                id : 1
            },
            {
                id : 2
            },
            {
                id : 3
            }
        ],
        text_id : 1
        },
    {
        remote : [
            {
                id : 4
            },
            {
                id : 5
            },
            {
                id : 6
            }
        ],
        text_id : 2
    }
];
const finalArray = fatArray.map( arr => {
  return arr.remote.map(elem => { return {text_id: arr.text_id, id: elem.id}})
}
)
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: THanks but I meant this jq:  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example28

Comment: oops my bad sorry !